# dpkg stuck in reading database

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

when trying to install something through apt-get or using dpkg -i to install a deb file the process gets stuck in reading the database. The last lines of the output read as follows:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ...
```

Then no progress at all. I already tried doing various combinations of

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade (update works, upgrade fails)
apt-get install -f (doesn't change anything)
dpkg --configure -a (doesn't seem to do anything)
dpkg --clear-avail (same as before)
```

I also tried using one of the backups of /var/lib/dpkg/status found in /var/backups, but with no success.

I checked the status of every package installed is OK

I first noticed the problem when I was running an update. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 which has dpkg 1.17.5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The following commands make it almost instantaneous:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo sync-available
```

sync-available is part of the dctrl-tools package.

Comment: My Ubuntu 14.04.3 was hanging at _[100%] Reading package lists_ for something like 20 minutes and that solved it.

Comment: After a while it happened again, and now I just do `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to speed it up again.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this by overwriting `/var/lib/dpkg/` with a backed up version.  Thankfully, I regularly make backups.  If you don't have a backup then maybe you can fetch the content of this directory from a live CD.